# Monitoring a group of applications built using nodeJS and non-nodejs (Java, C)

Tags: java, node.js, forever, monit, forever-monitor

We have an enterprise solution consisting of many independent components (servers) which will get deployed on multiple nodes.

Our solution consists of:
- 10+ Web apps (built with Node+Express)
- 10+ Java servers for internal processing
- External components such as Redis, MySQL

For deploying this solution, we use Ansible tool.  Now for the monitoring (starting, stopping and actual monitoring) part, there seem to be many choices:

- Monit
- Forever (only for NodeJS modules?)
- PM2     (same as forever?)
- Upstart (?)
- Monit + Forever
- Monit + Forever + upstart

I am unclear as to what is the right combination and why?  Initially I thought I should use Monit, but then I found some blogs which seem to suggest forever + monit, or upstart + monit and so on.

Are there any clear ideas here...

Comment: I would look at forever as an equivalent of supervisor which only restarts the process if it dies and does nothing else. Whereas in Monit - restarting the process is just a feature, there are plenty of other things you can do. You can monitor disk, CPU, memory and many more things with Monit. I would choose monit and leave Forever out of the equation for your use case. Not much sure about upstart though!

Comment: Yes, currently we are sticking to monit.